# How to reuse an Ansible variable inside jinja2 template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I've got the following:

**Ansible playbook:**

```
- 
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  #remote_user: ansible
  tasks: 
    - 
      name: "check dir size"
      shell: "du -sh /tmp/service/log"
      register: size
    - 
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ size.stdout }}"
    - 
      template: 
        src: template2.j2
        dest: ./file.out
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

**template2.j2**

```
{% for i in groups['all'] %}
{{ loop.index0 }} {{ hostvars[i].inventory_hostname }} {{ size.stdout }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Result:**

```
$ cat file.out 
0 host00 1.7G        /tmp/service/log
1 host11 1.7G        /tmp/service/log
2 host12 1.7G        /tmp/service/log
```

In the output file the directory size remains constant. 
How can I check the size of a directory for each host in the jinja2 loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`template2.j2` is being templated at localhost (because of `delegate_to: localhost`), so `size` is for localhost.

You might want to use `hostvars[i].size.stdout`, as you use for `inventory_hostname`.